I am trying to download file in SD card but it is getting downloaded in internal storage
I'm developing an Ionic app for reading and writing files on SD cards.
I can read the file, but when I try to download it, it goes to internal storage rather than SD card.
My code is provided below for any solutions.
downloadPdfAndSaveToSDCard(pdfUrl: string) {
    if (this.platform.is('cordova') && this.platform.is('android')) {
      const destinationPath = this.file.externalRootDirectory + 'Download/';
      const destinationFileName = 'pdfFileName.pdf'; 
      const assetUrl = 'assets/' + pdfUrl;

      this.http.get(assetUrl, { responseType: 'blob' }).subscribe(blob => {
        this.file.writeFile(destinationPath, destinationFileName, blob, { replace: true }).then(_ => {
          console.log('PDF saved to SD card successfully');
        }).catch(error => {
          console.error('Error saving PDF to SD card:', error);
        });
      }, error => {
        console.error('Error downloading PDF:', error);
      });
    } else {
      console.error('SD card is not available or this feature is not supported on this platform.');
    }
  }


What? - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
